# Returning and outputting 2 integers from 1 function

Tags: c++

i have to write a code that has a function that takes two integers and returns x as (a + b) and y as (a * b) and when i run it, it only outputs y. Why doesnt it output (or return) x?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int math (int a, int b) {
    int x, y;

    x = a + b;
    y = a * b;

    return x, y;
}

int main() {

    cout << math (5,3);

    getchar();
    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The return type of `math` is `int`, so this is what it returns (a single integer).

The expression `x, y` uses the [comma operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator). The comma operator evaluates `x`, discards its value, and then evaluates and returns `y`. In other words, `return x, y` is equivalent to `return y`.

You could use `std::pair<int,int>` to return a pair of integers.

Comment: You might also mention [`std::tie()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie)

Comment: @BillLynch How does `std::tie` help here?

Comment: You don't really want to suggest that he use `std::pair`, do you?  Do you really think that `first` and `second` are appropriate names for the fields?  (In practice, using `std::pair` is almost never a good solution if the code has to be maintained.)

Comment: @JamesKanze: It makes the use of the return value a bit nicer: https://gist.github.com/sharth/a96bc586966e3117aaf1 And you can use std::get() with std::pair so you don't need to see pair::first and pair::second. (But I'd rather see more use of tuple than pair)

Comment: @BillLynch Looks like obfuscation to me.  (But then I'd not use `std::pair` to begin with.)  There are some valid uses of `std::tie`, but in this case, it looks like you're using it to try to undo the damage done by using `std::pair` to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
return x, y;
```

does not do what you expect. The [comma operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zs06xbxh.aspx) returns only the value after the last comma - in this case, `y`. To return multiple values, you should use a `struct` or class containing both.

Answer (score 0):

You can only return one thing. You can put those in a struct, and return it. Simpler example.

```
struct xy {
    int x;
    int y;
};

xy math(int a, int b) {
    xy pair;
    int x, y;
    pair.x = a + b;
    pair.y = a * b;    
    return pair;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to make a function return more than one value.  The
first is to use out parameters, either references or pointers:

```
void
math( int a, int b, int& sum, int& product )
{
    sum = a + b;
    product = a * b;
}

int
main()
{
    int s;
    int p;
    math(5, 3, s, p);
    std::cout << s << ' ' << p << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The other is to define a class to contain the two values:

```
struct MathResults
{
    int sum;
    int product;
};

MathResults
math( int a, int b )
{
    return MathResults{ a + b, a * b };
}

std::ostream&
operator<<( std::ostream& dest, MathResults const& value )
{
    dest << value.sum << ' ' << value.product;
}

int
main()
{
    std::cout << math( 5, 3 ) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

In most cases, the second solution is to be preferred.